# numpy fromfunction dtype of index needs to be larger than dtype of values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dtype, numpy-dtype

Look at this example:

```
def l(x):
    return x%100

print(numpy.fromfunction(l, (300,), dtype=uint8)) #Fails!
print(numpy.fromfunction(l, (300,), dtype=uint16))#does not fail
```

Output of the first print statement:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
   34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
   51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
   68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
   85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99,  0,  1,
    2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
   19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
   36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52,
   53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
   70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86,
   87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99,  0,  1,  2,  3,
    4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
   21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37,
   38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,
   55,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
   16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
   33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43], dtype=uint8)
```

In the third-last line, you can spot the numbers not going up all the way to 100. This is where the overflow happens. (If you compare to the second print statement, this does not happen)

- Any value `mod 100` can be represented using `8 bits`, therefore a value of `uint8` should work.
- This is a 1-dimensional array with 300 entries. This cannot be represented in `uint8`.

## What I want:

- a way to use `fromfunction` with large indices and small values

## What I do not want:

- reshaping the array
- take up more space in memory

Comment: The 'unit8' is applied to the array that it sends to your function.  It does not pass the dtype to your function, or change the values your function returns.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 8 bit unsigned integer which can store values from `0 - 255` but you provide 300 as an argument for `l` function in `fromfunction()` function  which creates array before it calculates values. It saves all 300 values included those which are bigger than 255 before it get's return from `l` function. If you want to maintain your datatype you need to generate output before you append it into array like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = 300

def l(x):
    return x % 100

arr = np.zeros(a, dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(a):
    arr[i] = l(i)

print(arr)
```

**Output**

```
arr = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
96 97 98 99  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67
68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91
92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87
88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
```

If you need to use `fromfunction()` you need to dedicate enough memory for calculations.

Comment: You mean, there is no way to have both the built-in-parallelization/opimization of fromfunction and the smaller RAM requirements? (I don't want to believe that doing it fully in serial is the next-best way.)

Comment: I mean numpy constructs it on the go so it needs to perform calculations, if you're low on ram and performance instead of using `fromfunction` you can construct generator, list comprehension or even use cython with static types. I don't know a better way

Comment: `fromfunction` is not a "parallelization/optimization" tool.  It only works if your function takes the full array of indices.

Answer (score 0):

`fromfunction` may not be doing what you imagine.  If you look at the `[source]`, it just `np.indices` to create an array of values, and passes them (whole) to your function.  In this case it's the same as using `arange` to generate the input:

```
In [79]: l(np.arange(300, dtype='uint8'))
Out[79]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
      ...
        4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
       21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37,
       38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,
       55,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
       16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
       33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43], dtype=uint8)
```

Look at what `arange` produces for this dtype:

```
In [80]: np.arange(300, dtype='uint8')
Out[80]: 
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
        26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        ...
       234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246,
       247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255,   0,   1,   2,   3,
         4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,
        17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,
        30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,
        43], dtype=uint8)
```

`np.indices((300,),'uint8')` produces the same numbers.

`fromfunction` code:

```
args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

`fromfunction` doesn't do anything significant; it isn't "vectorizer" or memory or iteration "saver".  It just makes some values, and passes them to your function.